# Validating presence of attributes throwing error even when the field is not blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, activemodel

So I have been working on a multi-step form in ruby on rails (1.9.3) using Active model, following both the railscast #217 and #219 and am having problems with the validation the problem is that even if the attribute field is not blank it will still throw an error

```
1 error prohibited this wizard from being saved:
Validationattr can't be blank
```

I don't beleive it should be saving but this may just be something to do with the error
 . (I cannot use a form gem and must write this myself) let me know if you need any more information and i will be happy to provide.

**My controller code - (contollers/awizard_controller.rb)**

```
class AwizardController < ApplicationController

  def new
    # New Asset Wizard
    @wizard = Awizard.new(id: 1)
    # Set session variable as initial step
    session[:wizard_step] = @wizard.current_step
  end

  def update
    @wizard = Awizard.new(id: 1) unless !@wizard.nil?
    @wizard.current_step = session[:wizard_step] unless nil

    if @wizard.valid?
      if params[:back_button]
        @wizard.previous_step
      elsif @wizard.last_step?
        @wizard.save if @wizard.all_valid?
      else
        @wizard.next_step
      end
      session[:wizard_step] = @wizard.current_step
    end

    if @wizard.changed?
      render 'form'
    else
      @wizard.save
    end
  end

end
```

**My awizard Model - (models/awizard.rb)**

```
 class Awizard < Wizard
 validates :validationattr, :presence => true
 attr_accessor :validationattr

  def steps
    %w[validate_schedule validate_assets save_assets]
  end

 end
```

**My wizard Model - (models/wizard.rb)**

```
class Wizard
include ActiveModel::Validations
include ActiveModel::Conversion
include ActiveModel::Dirty
include ActiveModel::Naming

#This class is used to manage the wizard steps using ActiveModel (not ActiveRecord)

attr_accessor :id
attr_writer :current_step  #used to write to current step
define_attribute_methods [:current_step] #used for marking change

def initialize(attributes = {})
   attributes.each do |name, value|
     send("#{name}=", value)
   end
end

def current_step
  @current_step || steps.first
end

def steps
  %w[] 
end

def next_step
  current_step_will_change! #mark changed when moving stepped
  self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step)+1] unless last_step?
end

def previous_step
  current_step_will_change! #mark changed when moving stepped
  self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step)-1] unless first_step?
end

def first_step?
  current_step == steps.first
end

def last_step?
  current_step == steps.last
end

def all_valid?
  steps.all? do |step|
    self.current_step = step
    valid?
  end
end

def step(val)
  current_step_will_change!
  self.current_step = steps[val]
end

def persisted?
  self.id == 1
end

end
```

**My views -** 
**(/views/awizard/_form.html.erb)**

```
<%=  content_for :awizard_form do%>
  <%= form_for(@wizard) do |f| %>
    <%= render "#{@wizard.current_step}_step", :f => f %>
    <%= f.submit "Previous", :name => "back_button" unless @wizard.first_step? %>
    <%= f.submit "Continue", :name => "step" unless @wizard.last_step? %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**(/views/awizard/_step1.html.erb)**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :validationattr %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :validationattr %>
</div>
```

**(/views/awizard/_step2.html.erb)**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label 'Step2' %><br />
</div>
```

**(/views/awizard/_step3.html.erb)**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label 'Step3' %><br />
</div>
```

**Routes code**

```
resources :awizard
```

Comment: What are the parameters sent to the step2, when you submit the form with a value in the input of wizard's attribute validationattr ?

Comment: MrYoshiji this is what is causing the issue do you have some suggestions for what to do could you make this an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as [MrYoshiji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/976775/mryoshiji) stated without the parameters being passed through to step 2 the validationattr could not be validated in the wizard, adding in the controller a merge of the wizard params fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

The error is being thrown because the validationattr attribute is nil on Step 2.  I'm not sure of the logic, you may need to include it on subsequent posts.

Comment: Sorry but that really had no correlation to my problem